# let json support ISO 8859(åäö)?

Tags: php, json, utf-8, character-encoding

I have some data in the database that contains characters such as ä, å, and ö, and when I try to get the data with json, it returns null instead of the actual data.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Here is the code I am using:

```
    $result=  mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Recipes ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 5');
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
       $out[]=$row;
    }

    print(json_encode($out));
```

I tried everything I came across when googling, yet didn't solve the problem.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: i got the following error: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1

Comment: No actually the problem is that you need to give a utf8 encoded string to json_encode. There is nothing about json on that utf8 thread so i don't think it's a duplicate

Comment: the problem is not that i cant print out the characters on the page but that json encoding are ignoring these characters and returning null instead

Comment: `json_encode` expects **UTF-8 encoded strings**, it does not work with non-UTF-8 strings. You need to get data from your database in UTF-8 *or* convert it to UTF-8 by hand. The aforelinked UTF-8 question is very apropos.

Comment: japp thanks all . the answer in "UTF-8 character encoding battles json_encode()" question solved the problem